# How to check type of class in Java?

Tags: java

I'm a newbie to [Java](https://www.java.com/). I wrote a [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) with a method, which checks the Object type. I did my initial search in google and it was difficult to understand the articles available online. I would appreciate any help. I know that line **if(Object == dog)** doesn't work. How could I fix this?

```
public class dog {
    private String name;
    private String rasa;
    private int waga;

    public dog(String name, String rasa, int waga) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rasa = rasa;
        this.waga = waga;
    }
    public void printdog()
    {
        System.out.println(this.name);
        System.out.println(this.rasa);
        System.out.println(this.waga);
        if(Object() == dog)
        {
            System.out.println("dunno how to woof");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `instanceof` is the keyword. `if (this instanceof dog) ... ` and also have a look at the conventions (like classname with uppercase `class Dog` - just convention but most programmers adhere to it) Obs: instanceof does check if the object is a direct instance of the class or of any of its superclass, or if the object implements the given interface (if it is an interface)

Comment: What possible type could `this` have, if it isn't `dog` there? What are you trying to test to see if it isn't a `dog`?

Comment: I have to agree with Elliott, your code is nonsensical.  I think you may have this confused with something else.  Are you perhaps learning inheritance?  Are you supposed to declare an `Animal` class and then have `dog` inherit from it?

Comment: I did one big mistake , I didn't put whole code but for me that's closed

Answer (score 4):

You can use `instanceof` keyword to check type of object in java.

For example :

```
public class Stack  
{
    public Stack() {

}
public static void main(String[] args){
  Stack s1 = new  Stack();
  System.out.println(s1 instanceof Stack);
}
}
```

In you code you can do something like this:

```
if(this instanceof dog)
    {
        System.out.println("dunno how to woof");
    }
```

Comment: Instanceof does not return the object type but says if the object is of that class or a child of it.

Comment: I think this statement `object is of that class or a child of it` refers to the Object  type

Comment: I have two classes dog and germanshepherd , if i use instanceof germanshepherd will still say "dunno how to woof" option with getClass() is a better one .

Comment: @Coldoe got it. I didn't understand your question earlier.

Comment: @YugSingh My fault, I didnt precise, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

this.getClass() returns the class of the object.

Instance of tells you if it is of this type. In other words dog is instance of animal, dog is also instance of dog.

Comment: if(Object.getClass() == dog) but It doesnt work properly

Comment: `if (... getClass() == dog.class)` if you want that way

Comment: I have updated, you have to use your object, so for example this.getclass()

Answer (score 1):

This way you can check too.

```
  Dog s = new  Dog(dog, dunno, nowaga);

  if(s.getClass().equals( Dog.class))
  {
    System.out.println("dunno how to woof");
  }
```